Long and blonde haired guy killed by a robot coming out the television. Next scene is a graveyard with a veiled woman
There was this guy (feminish) with long blonde hair, sitting on a couch, smoking, with remote control in one hand, wearing an off-white long gown, in a large mostly empty room watching television (CRT).
He then voluntarily burns the back of his hand with the cigarette, and moans slightly. All of a sudden the television gets switched off right when something (can't recall) he really wanted to watch was going to happen. He then starts pressing the remote control to switch the television back on but in vain. He then lounges toward the television, which is placed on a large empty wall about the height of the guy (not tall). He then starts banging the television and all of a sudden a robotic figure comes out of the television and with two hands from the sides of the television (where he was banging it). It then grabs and lifts him up so that his head breaks into the screen of the television, potentially killing him. Yes it was most probably a horror.
Next scene, you see a guy standing under the shade of a tree with a graveyard in the background. Then a off-white veiled woman (face visible) comes up to the man, they talk (don't know about what). Same scene, different shot (camera changed) the woman's face is covered with a veil too.
Which movie could this be from?

A Nightmare On Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors, (1987), has a television scene like that. It's an actual girl, not a guy, watching television. She burns herself with cigarettes in an unsuccessful attempt to stay awake so she'll be safe from Freddy Kreuger.
The scene is on Youtube.
